# If two container are using InfiniBand one the same host, will data still occupy IB bandwidth?

Tags: infiniband

I'm trying to do some enhancement on the scheduling for distributed applications. And I'd like to confirm whether using InfiniBand one the same host will occupy IB bandwidth?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using RDMA with InfiniBand on the same host, the containers should not be using external bandwidth, but they will be using PCI-Express bandwidth.